# mssql cygwin result into variable

Tags: sql-server, bash, cygwin

```
 $ sqlcmd -Q "select state from sys.databases where name='test1'"
state
-----
   6

(1 rows affected)
```

so what i need is to use the result in this case the integer 6 as variable for a if eq statement.

How can i do this?

```
sqlcmd -Q "select state from sys.databases where name='test1'" | grep -v state | sed 's/^$\|^[ \t]*\|-\|(\|)\|1\|rows affected//g'
```

results in:

6

Comment: If `name` is primary key (thus returning only one entry) & it returns your answer always on the 3rd line, you could use this information as `awk 'NR==3'` or `sed '3!d'` & assign the result to variable using `$(....)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to store the result of your command, then test that variable:

```
myVar=$(sqlcmd -Q "select state from sys.databases where name='test1'" | grep -v state | sed 's/^$\|^[ \t]*\|-\|(\|)\|1\|rows affected//g')

if [ $myVar -eq 6 ]; then
    ...etc
fi
```